# Como retornar apenas valores repetidos no R?

Tags: r

suponha o seguinte dataframe:

```
ref<-data.frame(autores=c("AZEVEDO, L. S.; NASCIMENTO, E. F.; CANDEIAS, A. L. B.",
       "BERGER, R.; SILVA, J. A. A.; FERREIRA, R. L. C.; CANDEIAS, A. L. B.; RUBILAR, R.",
       "AZEVEDO, L. S.; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA",
       "SILVA, JADSON FREIRE; MIRANDA, RODRIGO QUEIROGA; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA",
       "OLIVEIRA, CLAUDIANNE BRAINER DE SOUZA; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA; TAVARES JUNIOR, J. R.",
       "SANTOS, AMANDA PEREIRA; SILVA, EDER BATISTA DA; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA; COSTA, MARIA APARECIDA TENÓRIO DA",
       "SILVA, JADSON FREIRE; MIRANDA, RODRIGO QUEIROGA; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA",
       "SILVA, JADSON FREIRE; PAZ, YENÊ MEDEIROS; LIMA-SILVA, PEDRO PAULO; PEREIRA, JOÃO ANTÔNIO DOS SANTOS; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA",
       "ALEXANDRE, FERNANDO DA SILVA; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA; GOMES, DANIEL DANTAS MOREIRA"))
```

```
autores
1                                                                            AZEVEDO, L. S.; NASCIMENTO, E. F.; CANDEIAS, A. L. B.
2                                                 BERGER, R.; SILVA, J. A. A.; FERREIRA, R. L. C.; CANDEIAS, A. L. B.; RUBILAR, R.
3                                                                                      AZEVEDO, L. S.; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA
4                                                     SILVA, JADSON FREIRE; MIRANDA, RODRIGO QUEIROGA; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA
5                                        OLIVEIRA, CLAUDIANNE BRAINER DE SOUZA; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA; TAVARES JUNIOR, J. R.
6                   SANTOS, AMANDA PEREIRA; SILVA, EDER BATISTA DA; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA; COSTA, MARIA APARECIDA TENÓRIO DA
7                                                     SILVA, JADSON FREIRE; MIRANDA, RODRIGO QUEIROGA; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA
8 SILVA, JADSON FREIRE; PAZ, YENÊ MEDEIROS; LIMA-SILVA, PEDRO PAULO; PEREIRA, JOÃO ANTÔNIO DOS SANTOS; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA
9                                          ALEXANDRE, FERNANDO DA SILVA; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA; GOMES, DANIEL DANTAS MOREIRA
>
```

Há um valor repetido: "SILVA, JADSON FREIRE; MIRANDA, RODRIGO QUEIROGA; CANDEIAS, ANA LÚCIA BEZERRA"

Consigo identificar através do "duplicated()"

```
duplicated(ref)

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Consigo identificar a posição onde está o valor duplicado com "which()"

```
which(duplicated(ref))

[1] 7
```

Mas o que eu queria mesmo era retornar um dataframe só com o valor repetido.

O arquivo em Excel: [referencias](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbbad5axd8rx9jd/coautoria.artigos.original.xlsx?dl=0)

Importo o arquivo

```
df<-rio::import("coautoria.artigos.original.xlsx")
```

Sendo um data.frame com varias colunas, uso a opção para manter todas as colunas

```
df2<-df[duplicated(df$artigo), ]
```

Tento organizar os artigos repetidos arrumando a ordem dos dados a partir da coluna "artigo". Mas o resultado não traz apenas artigos repetidos.

```
df2 %>% 
  arrange(artigo)
```

Alguns artigos repetidos aparecem, mas outros não.

Deveria retornar apenas os repetidos, não?

Um exemplo logo no começo do data frame: o 1o artigo que aparece ("A PRODUÇÃO DO ESPAÇO TURÍSTICO VIA ACUMULAÇÃO...") é repetido. O mesmo artigo é de autoria (coluna "docente") de "Itamar" e de "Edvania".

Deveria, então, aparecer um abaixo do outro, não? Um referente ao docente "Edvania" e outro ao docente "Itamar". Ou estou enganado?

Comment: `repetido <- ref[duplicated(ref), , drop = FALSE]`. É necessário usar `drop = FALSE` para manter a estrutura de dataframe.

Comment: Desculpa Rui, mas não entendi. O colchetes abre uma referência do tipo "linha" e "coluna", não é isso? Nesse caso, o "duplicated(ref)" seria a linha do "ref [ ]"  e o ", ," seria referente a "todas as colunas"? Não entendi. Que funciona, funciona! Testei aqui, mas queria entender

Comment: Sim, o `, , ` refere-se a todas as colunas. Quando só tem índice de linha é o mesmo que dizer *"esta linha, independentemente da coluna, isto é, todas"*. O mesmo acontece quando só tem índice de coluna(s), está a referir-se a todas as linhas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
df <- read_xlsx('./coautoria.artigos.original.xlsx')

df %>% add_count(artigo) %>%
  filter( n > 1)
```

Você já tentou utilizando add_count?
Não sei se é bem isso que você quer mas dessa forma eu testei e ele retornou valores duplicados.

Comment: Perfeito lmonferrari, era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Rui Barradas já respondeu nos comentários, vou expandir. Para facilitar a visualização e tornar a resposta mais geral, vou usar dados simulados:

```
set.seed(736)
letras <- sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10, replace = TRUE)
```

**vetor**

```
letras[duplicated(letras)]
```

**data.frame com uma coluna**

```
exdf <- as.data.frame(letras)

# Retornando como vetor:
exdf[duplicated(exdf), ]

# Mantendo a estrutura de data.frame
exdf[duplicated(exdf), , drop = FALSE]
```

**data.frame com várias colunas**

```
exdf$numero <- 1:nrow(exdf)

# Mantendo todas as colunas:
exdf[duplicated(exdf$letras), ]

# Apenas a coluna letras, como vetor:
exdf[duplicated(exdf$letras), "letras"]

# Apenas a coluna letras, mantendo a estrutura:
exdf[duplicated(exdf$letras), "letras", drop = FALSE]
#ou
exdf[duplicated(exdf$letras), ]["letras"]

# Mais de uma coluna como critério:
exdf[duplicated(exdf[c("letras", "numero")]), ]

# Todas as colunas (i.e. linhas iguais):
exdf[duplicated(exdf), ]
```

Conselho geral para R: aprenda a trabalhar com indexação e extração genérica. É um recurso básico e poderoso, mas muitas vezes desprezado. Consulte a ajuda com `?"["`. Em português, [esta aula da UFPR](http://leg.ufpr.br/%7Efernandomayer/aulas/ce083-2016-2/03_indexacao_e_selecao.html) dá uma boa geral.

Comment: Oi Carlos Eduardo, sua explicação é muito boa. Reproduzindo seus exemplos, eu consigo. Mas quando vou trabalhar com o meu df continuo sem sucesso. Não consigo perceber o que estou fazendo de errado.
Editei a pergunta para colocar o exemplo com o qual estou trabalhando. Coloquei o LINK DO ARQUIVO.

Comment: Quais colunas ou combinação de colunas duplicadas é critério para você? A referência completa? Use `ref[duplicated(ref$referencia.completa),]`. Título do artigo? `ref[duplicated(ref$artigo),]`. Combinação de título e autores: `ref[duplicated(ref[c("autores","artigo")]), ]`. Por isso fiz um exemplo genérico e dei a recomendação do tópico que sua dúvida envolve: entenda o princípio e pode usar para qualquer situação.

Comment: Agora foi Carlos. Muito obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Uma solução seria você chamar apenas as posições que estão repetidas.

No which(duplicated(df$x)) você descobre qual posição é duplicada na coluna 'x' do data.frame 'df', então a partir daí é só você chamar 'df' apenas com essas posições.

```
x<-sample(1:100, 100, replace=T) #Coluna com valores repetidos
y<-sample(1:100, 100, replace=F) #Coluna com valores únicos

df<-data.frame(x,y) #Construo o Data.frame

a<-which(duplicated(df$x)) #Atribuo 'a' apenas com as posições dos valores repetidos da coluna 'x' de 'df'

df[a,] #Chamo 'df' apenas com os valores de 'a', que são as posições dos valores repetidos da coluna 'x'.
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).